# Readout XML-file (from VSProject)

Tags: c#, xml

I need to readout an xml-file from my local VS2013 project. I have already access to my file, but not to the xml-file-content and get always the console-output: "Empty list". I can't find the bug... :/

**Here is my xml-file:**

```
<SystemParameters>

  <Velocities>

    <Axis>
      <Name>V1</Name>
      <DefaultValue>v1</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

    <Axis>
      <Name>V2</Name>
      <DefaultValue>v2</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

    <Axis>
      <Name>V3</Name>
      <DefaultValue>v3</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

  </Velocities>



  <Lengths>

    <Axis>
      <Name>L1</Name>
      <DefaultValue>l1</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

    <Axis>
      <Name>L2</Name>
      <DefaultValue>l2</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

    <Axis>
      <Name>L3</Name>
      <DefaultValue>l3</DefaultValue>
    </Axis>

  </Lengths>

</SystemParameters>
```

**And this is my C#-code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Untitled
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static List<string> ReadoutVelocities(XElement parameters)
        {
            List<string> velocitiesList = new List<string>();

            var velocity = from s in parameters.Elements()
                            select s.Element("Velocities");

            foreach (var p in velocity.Elements("Axis"))
            {
                velocitiesList.Add(p.Element("Name").Value);

                velocitiesList.Add(p.Element("DefaultValue").Value);
            }

            return velocitiesList;
        }


        public static void Query(XElement parameters)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Readout all velocity-parameters:\n");

            List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
            resultList = ReadoutVelocities(parameters);


            if(resultList.Count == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Empty list");

            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + resultList.ElementAt(i));
                    Console.WriteLine("DefaultValue: " + resultList.ElementAt(i + 1) + "\n");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n- - - - - End-Of-Line- - - - - \n");
            }
        }




        static void Main()
        {

            var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var textStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Untitled.DefaultValues.xml");
            var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(textStream);

            XElement parameters = XElement.Load(xmlReader);

            Query(parameters);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 bags

1. Get velocity
2. `resultList.Count` should be less

Here's full version

```
    public static void Query(XElement parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Readout all velocity-parameters:\n");

        var resultList = new List<string>();
        resultList = ReadoutVelocities(parameters);

        if (resultList.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty list");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.Count/2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + resultList.ElementAt(i));
            Console.WriteLine("DefaultValue: " + resultList.ElementAt(i + 1) + "\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n- - - - - End-Of-Line- - - - - \n");
    }

    public static List<string> ReadoutVelocities(XElement parameters)
    {
        var velocitiesList = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<XElement> velocity = parameters.Descendants("Velocities");
        foreach (XElement p in velocity.Elements("Axis"))
        {
            velocitiesList.Add(p.Element("Name").Value);

            velocitiesList.Add(p.Element("DefaultValue").Value);
        }
        return velocitiesList;
    }
```

Result output:

```
Readout all velocity-parameters:

Name: V1
DefaultValue: v1

Name: v1
DefaultValue: V2

Name: V2
DefaultValue: v2


- - - - - End-Of-Line- - - - -
```